# Help to solve Divide and Conquer

Tags: recursion, recursive-algorithms, substitution

How can I solve the following Divide and Conquer example? If you don't have enough time please just tell me the idea?
Thanks

$$T(n)=T\left(\frac{n}{7}\right)+T\left(\frac{11n}{14}\right)+n$$

Comment: What is the base case? For example, what is $T(0)$? What kind of value is $n$? Integers, or ...?

Comment: There is no base case... if it helps assume what you want

Comment: If there's no base case and no specification of the domain, there's no way to analyze it; the algorithm would never terminate.

Comment: You are right.. but what if T(1) = Θ(1) be the base case?

Comment: One approach to the base case is to define $T(0)$ to be some value like $0$ or $1$ and to take the divisions to be integer divides.  Then you get an expression you can always evaluate.  I did the first $50$ terms and it seemed to grow slowly, so would guess $T(n) \approx kn$ for some $k$.  Plug that into your equation and see what happens.

Comment: You can use [Akra–Bazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) method to find out that complexity is linear.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan, you are right its O(n). We can use "substitution method" to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We make the ansatz that $T(n) = kn$ asymptotically for some constant $k$.  Then when $n$ is large enough that the floor of the divides doesn't matter, we get $$kn=\frac 17kn + \frac {11}{14}kn+n\\k=14\\T(n) \sim 14n$$

Answer (score 0):

On each level of recursion, you get a cost of $\frac{13}{14}^in$, with i denoting the level starting at 0.

As we do not have a specific base case, we assume as base case a small, constant input size. In such cases we usually use as base case that we have input size 1, which would lead to $\log_7n$ recursions for the shallow part of the recursion tree, and $\log_\frac{14}{11}n$ for the deep part.

Normally we would take the $$\sum_{i=0}^{h} \frac{13}{14}^in$$ to get to the total cost of your recursion, where h is the height of the recursion tree. But in your specific case, you have a decreasing cost per recursion level ($\frac{13}{14}$ is < 1). This means that you total cost is dominated by the root of the recursion tree, which is n. You will have a total cost of

$T(n)=Θ(n)$